# Python enumerate inside for loop skips alternate items

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I have a situation where a for loop outside a class appears to be interacting with an enumerate inside the class.

Example code:

```
class MyContainerClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = []
    def __str__(self):
        return (len(self.collection) == 0 and 'Empty' or
                ', '.join(str(item) for item in self.collection))
    def __iadd__(self,item):
        print "adding {item}".format(item=str(item))
        self.collection.append(item)
        return self
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.collection)
    def discard(self,item):
        print "discarding {item}".format(item=str(item))
        for index, value in enumerate(self.collection):
            if value == item:
                print "found {value}=={item}".format(value=value,item=item)
                return self.collection.pop(index)
        return False

class MyItemClass(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
    def __str__(self):
        return '{value}'.format(value=self.value)
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if self.value == other.value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

c1 = MyContainerClass()
c2 = MyContainerClass()

c2 += MyItemClass('item1')
c2 += MyItemClass('item2')
c2 += MyItemClass('item3')
c2 += MyItemClass('item4')
c2 += MyItemClass('item5')
print "c1 is : {c1}".format(c1=str(c1))
print "c2 is : {c2}".format(c2=str(c2))

for item in c2:
    print "for got {item}".format(item=str(item))
    c1 += c2.discard(item)

print "c1 is : {c1}".format(c1=str(c1))
print "c2 is : {c2}".format(c2=str(c2))
```

Produces this output:

```
adding item1
adding item2
adding item3
adding item4
adding item5
c1 is : Empty
c2 is : item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
for got item1
discarding item1
found item1==item1
adding item1
for got item3
discarding item3
found item3==item3
adding item3
for got item5
discarding item5
found item5==item5
adding item5
c1 is : item1, item3, item5
c2 is : item2, item4
```

I'm sure it's something really obvious, possibly to do with the **iter** function, but I can't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying `c2.collection` (in `discard`) at the same time as iterating over it (`for item in c2:`). Don't do that.

Comment: Of course... So would adding __getitem__ to the container class and using a slice be the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: @PhilipDG: Personally I'd just write `for item in tuple(c2):`. But if the way you'd usually do this for a list is to write `for item in c[:]` then yes, implement `__getitem__` to handle slices. I guess it's a question of how list-like you want to make `MyContainerClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't safe to modify a container while you're iterating over it.

In this case, what's happening is that the iteration just keeps track of the number of elements that have gone by. So when you take out item1, the iterator knows it's already gone past the first item in the container... which is now `item2`. Thus, it happily continues on to  `item3`.